# pixy.init has no atribut init & pixy_init is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

i've had some code run with pixy(cmucam5) package imported and it got error cause there is no atribute init
and i've tried to run sample code from the pixy and it got same error
can anyone help me

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ky0.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Dsl.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WRCF.png)

[This is the sample codes that i've tried to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdmVX.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.